# What do the PAL and NTSC abbreviations stand for?

Tags: terminology

I often hear these abbreviations while talking about regionalisation in gaming.

I think PAL is from Europe, and NTSC in North America, but what do these two abbreviations stand for and mean?

Comment: Never Twice the Same Color.

Comment: This is trivially researched.

Comment: On any other Stack Exchange site, this question would be quickly closed...

Comment: @cybermonkey Close votes are not for bad questions, they are for off-topic questions.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Incorrect, there are multiple close reasons for other than off-topic.

Comment: @cybermonkey None of which are "low quality". That's a downvote reason.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer I'm not here to discuss the merits of close votes & downvotes.

Comment: @cybermonkey That's the fastest u-turn I've ever seen

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Not at all, I just don't want to flood the comments with a pointless argument, and you shouldn't either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56830/discussion-between-danmakugrazer-and-cybermonkey).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**These are the two most common video standards used in the world.** While VHS video format is the same throughout the world, video standard or electronic signals that are recorded on the cassette varies from country to country. [See more here.](http://ihffilm.com/videostandard.html)

[Another way to describe them:](http://www.diffen.com/difference/NTSC_vs_PAL) NTSC and PAL are two color encoding systems that affect the visual quality of content viewed on analog TVs, and to a much smaller degree, the content on HDTVs.

NTSC (National Television System Committee) is the video system or standard used in North America and most of South America. In NTSC, 30 frames are transmitted per second, with each frame being made up of 525 individual scan lines. The resolution is 720x480 and  it offers manual color correction.

PAL (Phase Alternating Line) is the main video system or standard used in most other parts of the world. In PAL, 25 frames are transmitted per second, with each frame being made up of 625 individual scan lines. The resolution is 720x576 and it offers automated color correction.

There is technically a third standard, SECAM, that is used in France and some other Eastern European countries.

Comment: Just a note - for NTSC, it's not used in all the listed countries since digital conversion, as far as I understand it.

Comment: Hmm okay, I'll remove specifics and just leave it as a general thing! Thanks

Comment: Analogue TV doesn't actually have a fixed horizontal resolution. The horizontal resolution can be anywhere from 1 to whatever the bandwidth of the transmission medium allows without blurring it all together. The horizontal resolution is also somewhat variable, there's always 525 or 625 individual scan lines, but the number them actually used to display video varies. Also, it would be incorrect to describe the resolution used as an aspect ratio, which was always 4:3 for NTSC over-the-air transmissions and either 4:3 or 16:9 for PAL.

Comment: @n_palum *These are the two most common video standards used in the country.* Did you mean used in the world?

Comment: Updates made accordingly. Thanks for the additional info Ross

Comment: Also, NTSC is known as "Never The Same Color" and PAL as "Perfection At Last". PAL is also usually better than NTSC on bad weather (doesn't matter now, since analog TV is pretty much dead). Also, their refresh rate is based in the mains' duty cycle.

Comment: Technically NTSC runs at about 29.97 frames per second, not 30. The exact number is 30,000 / 1,001 fps.

Comment: @Dithermaster *color* NTSC, anyway. Black and white NTSC was exactly 60 fields per second.

Comment: "_France and some other Eastern European countries_" makes it sound like France is an Eastern European country.

Comment: @You It's not really accurate, it was France, USSR, and many client states and formers colonies (some African and Eastern European countries).

Answer (score 5):

The names come from [video encoding modes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PAL#PAL_vs._NTSC).

[PAL (Phase Alternating Line)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PAL) - this is more commonly used in Europe and parts of Asia/Africa.

[NTSC (National Television System Committee)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTSC) - this is commonly used in the Americas, South Korea and Japan (or, well, was until digital conversion).